# C - Modifying a file

Tags: c

I have a solution here that supposedly opens a file and changes the last character of it. I don't quite understand how this works. Could you please explain?

```
void readlast()
{
   int handle = open("./file.txt", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR);
   if (handle < 0)
   {
       return;
   }
```

Okay, this part opens the file and if it doesn't work, returns. 
First question: Why is a file opening an integer (`int handle`)? What is being stored in it?

```
   char c='N';
   lseek(handle, -2*sizeof(c), SEEK_END);
```

`lseek` apparently changes the location of a reader. So I guess this sets the reader to the end of a file(`SEEK_END`). But why do we need an offset of `-2*sizeof(c)` if we just want to write one character?

```
   write(handle, &c, sizeof(c));
   close(handle);
}
```

I do understand this last part.

Thank you!

Comment: _Why is a file opening an integer (int handle) ?_ : Because the API has been defined so. _What is being stored in it ?_ : it's an opaque value that identifies the open file. The only thing you can do with that handle is to use it for file operations such as read or write, and closing the file with `close`.

Comment: Is it a text file with a newline in the end? `-1` is for the last character (first from the EOF), `-2` - to skip the newline...

Comment: The int that you get back for the opened file is just a file descriptor.  Your OS knows the process's opened files and their descriptors. Kernel keeps it's own struct for each opened file in each process. lseek(3) with SEEK_END means move cursor to the end of file + offset. https://linux.die.net/man/3/lseek

Comment: For `-2*sizeof(c)` - the -2 is to move back two characters from the end, so you can overwrite that character. Otherwise, the write would add a character to the file. Presumably `-2` rather than `-1` to leave an end-of-line character intact (though an end-of-line on Windows is two characters). The sizeof(c) is redundant - `c` has type `char`, so the size will always be `1`. The C definition of a byte is `char` (even in rare cases where a byte isn't 8 bits wide).

Answer (score 0):

1. Normally a file descriptor is returned by open() and it is an integer. 0 and 1 are customarily standard I/O.
2. File size - 2 [octets] is the offset of last character/byte.